# How to mock new instance where it return interface reference

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a scenario like this

```
MyInterface myObject = new MyInterfaceImplementedClass();
myObject.get(...)
```

I want to mock the MyInterfaceImplementedClass, I tried like below

```
private MyInterface mockMyObject
private MyInterfaceImplementedClass mockMyClassObject

// the below compilation error 
whenNew(MyInterfaceImplementedClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockMyObject);
// no compilation error but not giving mocking instance at runtime
whenNew(MyInterfaceImplementedClass.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockMyClassObject);
```

Please help me on this

Comment: What does "*but not giving mocking instance at runtime"* mean?

Comment: In using PowerMockito, it is critically important that we see your `@RunWith` and `@PrepareForTest` annotations on the test class. Please edit your question to include them. (PowerMock manipulates the Java classloader, so those annotations are often the difference between a failure and a success.) If you aren't using those annotations, please tell us that, too: it might be a very quick solution to your problem!

Comment: Hi Jeff, Yes, you are right, after adding my test class in side @PrepareForTest, it works as expected, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Solved in the comments:

> after adding my test class in side @PrepareForTest,  it works as expected

In short, Mockito writes a generated subclass for the class you're trying to mock, which allows it to intercept the behavior of *overridable* methods (i.e. non-final instance methods). This handles all interfaces and most abstract and concrete classes. However, if you're trying to mock the behavior of `final` or `static` methods, including constructors, there's nothing Mockito can do<sup>1</sup>: the consuming class contains a reference to the exact real implementation without a lookup to the virtual method table. The only way out is to *rewrite and replace the bytecode of an existing class*, which is exactly what PowerMock does.

It can often just overwrite the class you're trying to mock, but in certain circumstances you need to list the class under test or the test class itself.

Consequently, almost all tests that exercise PowerMock's features require a `@PrepareForTest`, as well as a `@RunWith` statement that ensures that the test class uses PowerMock's classloader to enable that rewriting.

---

<sup>1</sup> since Mockito 2.1, Mockito can use instrumented classloaders to do *some* of the things that were previously only available in PowerMock.

Comment: Great Explanation Jeff, Thank you

Comment: @user3346145 You're welcome! If you're satisfied with this answer, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/201031) by clicking the checkmark above and next to the answer box. It's a nice way to tell folks that this question has been answered, and gives you a little rep bonus for following through. Good luck with your work!